# Имеет ли смысл после каждой математической операции производить округление для борьбы с неточными вычислениями?

Tags: javascript, математика

Или не надо изобретать велосипед? А надо просто исходить из критичности неточных вычислений для работы программы, и там где это критично - использовать тип данных Decimal (в JS, видимо, реализуемый какой-нибудь сторонней библиотекой).

```js
'use strict';
// Просто примеры.
var a = (0.1 + 0.2) * 10;
var b = (0.1 + 0.7) * 10;
// Без округления.
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(Math.ceil(a));
console.log(Math.floor(b));
// С округлением (хотя надо было уже после сложения округлять).
console.log(Math.round(a * 100) / 100);
console.log(Math.round(b * 100) / 100);
console.log(Math.ceil(Math.round(a * 100) / 100));
console.log(Math.floor(Math.round(b * 100) / 100));
```

```js
'use strict';
function r(a) {
  return Math.round(a * 100) / 100;
}
console.log((r(5 / 2 * 10)).toFixed(100));
console.log((r(r(5 / 2) * 10)).toFixed(100));
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: все зависит от того, что именно ты считаешь

Comment: @Grundy Вы имеете ввиду критичность ошибки из-за неточных вычислений?

Comment: В том числе. Например, какой результат ты ожидаешь в случае: `5 / 2 * 10`? Для этого примера если округлять на каждом действии и только в конце будут разные результаты.

Comment: @Grundy Да, я об этом подумал, что постоянно округляя - я ещё хуже сделаю.  Хотя в вашем примере всё ок, я добавил код.

Comment: Ну ты же догадываешься, что если после деления будет три знака после запятой, то твое решение сломается? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
в зависимости от задачи и важности
например в java банковский софт для подсчёта денег 
используется int - т.е. целочисленный тип, т.к. погрешности с такими вещами, 
как деньги - неприемлемы :)
```

Comment: По-моему тип данных для решения проблемы неточных вычислений называется Decimal, а не Integer. Хотя я не спец по Java.

Comment: имеется ввиду, что числа с плавающей точкой вообще не используются, для операций с деньгами, ибо погрешности есть всегда с плавающей точкой

Comment: Не, это не поможет. Потому что банк может производить операции с процентами или делением - неточные вычисления всё равно возникнут. Нужен специальный тип данных Decimal.

Comment: int в Java ограничен максимальным положительным числом 2 147 483 647. Если допустить, что последние две цифры это копейки, то остаётся всего 21 474 836.47, что даже для масштабов некоторых физических лиц может часто вызывать ошибку Integer number too large.

Answer (score 0):

Округляя промежуточные результаты вычисления вы уменьшаете точность итогового результата. Для борьбы с неточными вычислениями обычно прибегают к повышению точности, например, увеличением количества знаков после запятой. При округлении результата нужно убедится в том, что стратегий округления одинаковы во всех местах.

Comment: Может перед запятой? 

Comment: При чтении слева направо - после запятой, другими словами - справа от запятой. В общем случае, я имею в виду при расчёте значений увеличить точность дробной части. Из числа 12.34 сделать 12.345678. А если это невозможно, то заполнить нулями.

Comment: Заполнить нулями справа? Они же будут просто отброшены. Это же Number, а не String. 

Comment: @ValeraRybakoff, имелось виду, что в случае, если требуется точность в два знака после запятой, в расчетах оперировать числами с 4 знаками, то есть можно округлять _на каждой операции_ до 4 знаков, а при выводе конечного результата округлять до двух.

Comment: Да, для Number будут просто отброшены до первого встречного "не нуля". Во всяком случае, эта особенность не играет роль в данном вопросе.